# Lookups inside tables.. still 'evil' if I use bound columns? What is less evil?

Tags: ms-access, database-design, lookup

What if I have it where I (in the design mode for my table, in a particular field) use the combo box to lookup the ID and the value and then make the value my bound column?

I understand I'm losing the ability to see relationships that I've made in this way on the relationships database tool. Am I losing anything else?

In other articles I've researched, they talk about queries not working correctly or the database being too rigid/hard to change after the fact. I don't necessarily see those problems.(although I'm still learning Access! =) )

When I build a Query to test if it returns the ID or the value, it returns the value, so what's the real problem here?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you have a domain table that looks something like this:

```
DomainTable
-----------
DomainID
DomainValue
```

The rows of your table might look something like this:

```
1   Male
2   Female
3   Other
```

And you have another table where you want to include either the `DomainID` or the `DomainValue`.

Generally, you would use the `DomainID`.  This allows you to make a change to the domain value without having to make the change in hundreds of places.

On the other hand, if you want changes to the domain values to **not be reflected** in your other tables, you would use the `DomainValue`. This is important when creating a log file, as one example.

Comment: Got it. So what you're saying is that if I use a lookup within a table and then later want to go back and change that value (for example from 'soccer player' to 'soccer star') it wouldn't change throughout. Correct?

Comment: @Josh Croft: Yes, that's correct.  You would have to change "soccer player" to "soccer star" in the various tables in which the text is located, rather than the one place in the domain table.